# PHP Regex pattern as string to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, regex, json

So, this may not be as straight forward as I had hoped after spending a new hours looking... thus why I'm writing my own question after browsing others to no avail. It usually leads me to a question around PHP to JS regex compatibility or conversion and is not applicable - as far as I can see, feel free to correct me - to my question.

My target is to create a JSON array of custom validation rules to use within the JS "formvalidation" plugin, with the array generated server side in PHP (using CI as the MVC framework), [in which a reference to the required structure can be found here](http://formvalidation.io/settings/#settings-structure).

This array of custom validation rules is **currently** generated within a PHP controller, JSON encoded, passed to the view and then parsed via JSON.parse into a variable to get the required object based structure instead of strings; which is the easy bit and works.

**Here's the kicker and where I'm stuck;** one of the parameters within the validation rules can be a Regex pattern. Within the PHP array, it has to be kept within quotes, but when it hits JS, it needs to be taken out of the quotes to become a regular expression object(? unsure if that is the correct terminology).

I've looked into using the `RegExp` object to create a new regular expression; `var x = new RegExp("string","/modifier");` for example. But the problem comes from the regular expression being nested within a JSON array when you don't know what the key is going to be.

My current structures are as follows:

PHP Array of validation rules, in the required structure as per the plugin documentation:

```
$formValidationConfig = array(

        // Validation rules to be passed to the formvalidation plugin

        'name'  =>  array(

                        // Optional
                        // Element name as the array key

                        // Formatting of the array content:
                        // http://formvalidation.io/settings/#settings-structure
                        // [key] Validators (necessary wording) => [sub array]
                        //                                         [key] Validation Rule => [sub array]
                        //                                                                  [key] Validation Rule Name  => [val] Validation Parameter :: optional pair
                        //                                                                  [key] Error Message         => [val] Message Content

                        'validators' => array(

                                            'notEmpty'      =>  array(
                                                                    'message'   =>  'The full name is required'
                                                                ),
                                            'regexp'        =>  array(
                                                                    'regexp'    =>  '/^[a-zA-Z\\\s]+$/',    // Optional
                                                                                                            // The triple backslash is necessary due to JS and JSON both parsing the array
                                                                    'message'   =>  'The full name can only consist of alphabetical characters'
                                                                ),
                                            'stringLength'  =>  array(
                                                                    'max'       =>  50, // Optional
                                                                    'message'   =>  'The full name must be less than 50 characters'
                                                                )
                                        )
                    )
    );

// -----
// Further down the page (scroll)
// -----

$page = array(
    'formValidationConfig'  =>  json_encode( $formValidationConfig )
);
```

The Javascript to parse out the array:

```
var validationRules = JSON.parse( '<?=$formValidationConfig;?>' );
```

...aaaand the JSON output:

```
Object
    name: Object
        validators: Object
            notEmpty: Object
                message: "The full name is required"
            regexp: Object
                message: "The full name can only consist of alphabetical characters"
                regexp: "/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/"
            stringLength: Object
                max: 50
                message: "The full name must be less than 50 characters"
```

Which works for everything but the regex. With all of the objects and properties set correctly, bar obviously ... the regex.

I've had a few ideas:

- Send the regex items in a seperate array. Once they reach the page, parse them int RegExp objects, but make reference somehow to a pre-defined variable name within the PHP array.
- Loop through the JSON array and parse out the string quotes, just leaving the regular expression within the JSON array.

Please, shower me in some knowledge and teach me where I'm going wrong!

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: `var re = new RegEx(<?php echo json_encode($regex_without_delimiters); ?>);`?

Comment: Have you tried without the openning and closing '/' ?

Comment: @RonDadon that worked perfectly! Thank you! I can't believe it was something so simple... then again it always seems to be! haha